# Number of distributions leaving none of $n$ cells empty

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

The solution for the number of distributions leaving none of the $n$ cells empty (with unlike cells and $r$ unlike objects) is given by

$$A(r,n)=\sum_{\nu=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{\nu}\binom{n}{\nu}(n-\nu)^{r}$$ (although I have seen the same expression summing from $\nu=0$ to $n$).

*By the way, if anyone knows which one is correct, please let me know. However, that's not the question.*

I have read that this expression provides a solution to a famous problem. I'd like to know where can I find more information about this solution and which famous problem solves. I already tried [An Introduction to Combinatorial Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691023654) by John Riordan and [Certain distributions of unlike objects into cells](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2688836) by Morton Abramson but their treatment of this particular expression is very brief.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick note: both are correct; what does the $\nu=n$ term in the sum look like?

Comment: $A(r,n)$ gives the number of onto functions from an $r$-element set to an $n$-element set; is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Mike: I don't think so, unless that behind that interpretation remains an old and famous problem.

Comment: There are a lot of references and some formulas for these numbers in the OEIS: http://oeis.org/A019538.  In general, when you have some numbers that you're interested in learning more about, the OEIS is a great place to start looking.

Comment: Thank you for that webpage. Very useful indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  I am not sure what you mean by a famous problem that this sequence solves; you seem to already have given the standard combinatorial interpretation.

The Stirling numbers of the second kind occur in a certain formula for the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n k^r$; perhaps that's the problem you're thinking of?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I know these are the Stirling numbers of the second kind (actually, Riordan gives the expression above with those numbers). Unfortunately, I'm looking for information not explicitly stated in terms of $S(n,k)$. Regarding the formula you wrote, no, I didn't have in mind that (now that you mention $\sum_{k=1}^n k^r$, to which famous problem that expression refers?).

Comment: @Robert: are you sure that "partitions of an n-element set into k non-empty subsets" isn't the "famous problem" that you read about?

Comment: @Robert, @Qiaochu: Could the "famous problem" be the problem of enumerating the partitions of $n$?

Comment: @Arturo: I'm not sure. It could be, though. Can you state the conditions for such enumeration?

Comment: @Qiaochu, Arturo: It's not strictly necessary to know which problem was solved by this solution (although, I would be nice). I could very well be satisfied with a good treatment on this particular expression.

Comment: @Robert: what do you mean by a good treatment?  What, exactly, do you want to know?

Comment: @Qiaochu: Not much... A nice introduction and a few identities.

Comment: @Robert: there might be a discussion in Stanley's _Enumerative Combinatorics_; I am pretty sure there is a discussion in Flajolet and Sedgewick's _Analytic Combinatorics_.  These numbers show up implicitly in a recent math.SE question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14245/formal-proof-of-exponential-rule/14251#14251) as the coefficients of (exp(x) - 1)^n, and they also have a somewhat interesting ordinary generating function.  Finally, they allow you to write down the generating function sum n^k x^n "explicitly," which leads to the application I mentioned.

Comment: Great! I'm going to take a look at those references.

Comment: For completeness: Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics* contains several identities dealing with the Stirling numbers of the second kind in pages 33-35. Flajolet's *Analytic Combinatorics* provides some properties in pages 59-60 and a brief explanation in page 100. Additionally, I found a very nice chapter of combinatorics in Harris and Hirst's *Combinatorics and graph theory* (page 231 for a survey on the Stirling numbers).